# Event for unhandled exceptions in Silverlight background threads?

Tags: silverlight, multithreading, exception

Is there a usable equivalent of `AppDomain.UnhandledException` for Silverlight? I say usable, because, although the method exists in Silverlight, MSDN has it marked as `[SecurityCritical]`.

What I'd like is to receive notification of Exceptions happening on background or ThreadPool threads so that I can log them. `Application.UnhandledException` was another candidate, but it looks like that only recieves exceptions from the UI thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Silverlight 3? I just put together a simple SL3 application that showed that Application.UnhandledException was notified on unhandled exceptions from the UI thread, a thread pool thread, a worker thread and a background worker thread.

You may have convinced yourself prematurely. :)

Comment: Verified the same here. The event is as close as you'll get to an app domain unhandled exception handler in the Silverlight world.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I am using Silverlight 3, so I'll check my App again.

Comment: I do indeed receive events from other threads. I was mislead because the error handling code I installed in Application.UnhandledException tried to display some UI, and of course, it can't because it is called on the thread in which the exception occurred, and not the UI thread - so it was throwing an exception of its own!

Comment: Awesome--glad you found why. :)